# Change Knock gem return rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, jwt, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello thank you for reading me, I am trying to change the default return from the knock gem of rails, it returns a json with just a jwt element.

```
{
    "jwt": "token"
}
```

but I want to add elements to that response:

```
{
    "jwt": "token",
    "my element": "element 2"
}
```

is it possible, or need to make another request using that token to return more data?

If you could help me I will be very grateful, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
render json: {
      jwt: "token",
      element: "you data",
    }, status: :ok
```